# bluej: how to create object with Date type

Tags: java, arrays, date, arraylist, types

How can I give my datamember `date` from the type `Date` a value?
I added in my class the **import java.util.*** statement but I can't find a way to give it a value. It isn't a string like "12-11-2014"
This is one of my first project with Java, so I don't have many experience. ;-)

Greetings Moleculation

```
import java.util.*;

public class Training
{
// data members (instance variables)
private double distance;  // in km
private double time;  // in seconden
private String type;
private Adres address;
private Date date;


public Training(int distance, int time, String type, Adres address, Date date)
{
    // initialise data members (if necessary)
    this.distance = distance;
    this.time = time;
    this.type = type;
    this.address = address;
    this.date = date;
}
// getters
public double getDistance()
{
    return distance;
}
public double getTime()
{
    return time;
}
public String getType()
{
    return type;
}
public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}
public Adres getAddress()
{
    return address;
}

// setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do -

```
Date date = new Date();
```

This will assign the current system date to `date`.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to assign another date for example 06-10-14?

Comment: You can find this from here- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class instead. You can then use something similar to:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
```

Remember, that can use the constants in the class too, e.g. :

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calender.MARCH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to SagarVimal's answer, you can use an instance of the `GregorianCalendar` class to represent any date:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int day);
```

To turn it into a Date object, use:

```
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Sources:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html
http://isolani.co.uk/blog/java/CreatingJavaUtilDateObjectUsingGregorianCalendar

Comment: `calendar.getTime()` is a Date object, so you don't need to create another one.

Comment: Ahaa okee thanks, and you can I add this to my code?

Comment: @Moleculation what do you mean? You are free to add this to your code, if that is what you mean.