# How to get the Date from a windows system in BlueJ?

Tags: java, bluej

I am just an average BlueJ user. I have only started using it recently. Can you guys help me get the current Date. I am trying to build a program that asks the user their birthday and tells their exact age in days, months and years, by checking the current date and time. I can make the calculations on my own, I just need to get the current date from the system. Any Idea on how to do that?

Comment: `new Date();` ? or for more complexity see `Calendar` or if you are using java8 `LocalDateTime` Did you try searching for this?

Comment: How to get a Date on Valentines...

Comment: @Reimeus No idea, I am a developer

Answer (score 0):

It is very helpful to copy-and-paste your current code so we can see what you have done. Stack Overflow (SO) is really a site for people who have done their research, searched several webpages, tried several different things, and are stuck. That being said, here is a very quick sample code that returns the date.

```
import util.Date;

/**
 * Class ReturnDate returns the current date.
 */
public class ReturnDate
{
    //Declare variable of type Date
    private Date date;

    /**
     * Constructor sets up the program properly
     */
    public ReturnDate()
    {
        //Create a new Date object called "date"
        date = new Date();
    }

    /**
     * Method printDate() prints the current date to the 
     * terminal window.
     */
    public void printDate()
    {
        //Print the current date to the terminal window
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    }
}
```

Note, that if you had spent some time searching, you could have found this answer yourself too. For example, the links below are the first two hits of a Google search with the terms "BlueJ return current date". Note they are both from SO!

[print current date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717733/print-current-date-in-java)

[bluej: how to create object with Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471328/bluej-how-to-create-object-with-date-type)